# Verify message with openssl ECDSA_verify()

Tags: c++, openssl

I want to use openSSL in CPP  to verify messages with ECDSA.
I have the data from the server which contains the message and the signature pair. Along with the server has provided the curve parameters:-

```
(p,a,b, Base Point (Gx, Gy), Order of Base Point (r))
```

and the public key.

Using these values I want to verify message with `ECDSA_verify().`

As I am new to openssl, I don't know how to use these values to verify the signature.

Answer (score 0):

When doing much the same - I found the files

```
test/ecdsatest.c
crypto/ecdsa/ecdsatest.c
```

in the base openssl distribution a easy starting point. (OpenSSL calls the base point the subgroups generator). ec_key_st and ec_group_st in

```
crypto/ec/ec_lcl.h
```

are the final bit needed to map things (for the point and the group, the a and b, etc).